# How to infer types from array of string values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

### Aim

1. I'd like for TS to infer the types based on the values (static) passed to an array of strings.
2. The actual function implementation should give the correct result aswell

### Problem

Create a function, called:

```js
export function CreateColoursPalette(tints, palette) {
  //...
}
```

### Usage

```js
const tints = {
  sun: createColour({
    10: '#FEF0D6',
    30: '#FCE0AC',
    50: '#FBD183',
    80: '#F8BA44',
    100: '#F7AB1B',
  }),
  azure: createColour<110>({
    10: '#FEF0D6',
    30: '#FCE0AC',
    50: '#FBD183',
    80: '#F8BA44',
    100: '#F7AB1B',
    110: '#FFE0AC',
  })
};


const colours = CreateColoursPalette(tints, {
  primary: ['sun', 'azure'],
  secondary: ['sun'],
  tertiary: {
    neutral: ['sun', 'azure'],
  },
});
```

1. tints is an object which holds all the available tints you have
2. palette is an object which holds an array of string values, which are keys from tints object

The function should **transform** the **palette** object, by replacing each string key in the array with its respective value from the tints object.

### IntelliSense

When we call colours, TS should infer correct types, i.e.

```js
colours.
     //| primary
     //| secondary
     //| tertiary

// here TS should infer only 3 possible options due to the array above
colours.primary.
             //| sun
             //| azure

const [baseColour, tints] = colours.primary.sun;
tints.
   //| 10 | 30 | 50 | 80 | 100

colours.secondary.
               //| sun

colours.tertiary.
              //| neutral

const [baseColour, tints] = colours.tertiary.neutral.azure
tints.
   //| 10 | 30 | 50 | 80 | 100 | 110
```

### My current solution (with wrong TS typing)

To make this question less intimidating, I've put my solution into the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/PQKhF5K7oKCgBAWwPYBMCmAbAzgOgBccEp4ZzIxhYMAPABxQCcCECBPejBAIQEMcGACoBLAHZESCAIwAGBAB8EAZnlKArGoQAOLXNkBuWDQbNWHLglESA0hnY4APEIR0CGMWmJiArkgBGGExS-ILWRAB8IQLC4pJKQkYmjCxsnNzhTi5uHl4IvgFB0WFxOFHgCADesAgIANoA1vYI4lZxdg7OEQC6AFwIOARM4gDmRgC%20SXQp5ukIAMIoWCg%20TB3E4DWKCADkOD5iO1tKO3wAXqsYR7UnaHxMDQBqIksYBNfbOwDGABb3Xyg%20FgPicsCIRj8CABxJj2HZTUypCzcRbLVZZKSolZrexlKTVWp1AFo4KtACitCGfC%20BEcWNW6wANFYev06oNhmIRszMo4CoFggAyXgxTI9CYImYtCRBABm1O4AAVhkh7uw6Ziltj1lECQhgMAEGSRAQfkV6TiHHVuoolBacFt6Cq1f15q5KbliBb1ggAPwLa0IV0TYzTMzS9xMeVfbiCAGeNUaire3G6rYGo0ms3BFNWm0KO1a9FbOMoBNMdiu93uTxeouW4j%20%20aB4OwcahxGsOJyhVsIIEESJt3J%20s6qpbSMDl3j2q1DPG03m0e4wMFhb1h2z-IYHxUrBVnK19ckn1NlsLIxbwSqiQiL44A8eo%205xsBm2t2qTNsdqXdqO9xUgTedxnE1E9Uy2Q88mVERVQrLpGS2WpS3LdUhAiRCt0nQd4PQqp21gUAIAoCgyEgBBdxEXBCA2UgSIoKgf3DWUDhpF4xAQL5YT4dwLVAqDvD8AViliCQygACgnUp%20l5dDYAASjZDlRh5UouhtPUMwAd24LSqKwCjBHqfQbQEBBsQQfwYgQWVmFcAA3IJ2E4%20stnjQZLJiC0pAHMS6hMpJalhAhVg4uorMEC1mV8ohuhDQjDV%20DAvgaYgRFlBA%20A4lB-AAK2SrtiAwJB6A4WAWLENiyxaHAAHk8rJEqOHEnLcv6LL2EU8y8pqhAACVkuYNBHGUrlmQ6tMgreUKEEkrdWoQQVhQzQBeDcACR38h8LADKytAKM8DBZXEDA9qSlKkIQer8ppPAmgcFq8vkvAsA8EZTRIcj5CWi7Wrwdyhh8Gk7MQK6Cq2eT4oqqqOJEOq8vE%20ygXasROv6RGDNh49sWIPVgpm5EUAy9GPoqHZWoKnZFuFABCWGrsa0r2ARoEIe-crWIHarYYAQSYJg%20DQ6tPQGIZRikUaRgiZn90ylGuuJzGhEDXHpqYDjef59g8B5vmBel1mCKhzmYZwABlIZpeR1GEAV4gJZnBA8bVtIuEJm2gRJ3YJcptcFbEQYspjN3zc5MY2aN9iaseIERDQC1xI5foJei6SRdD60uo5XqXwdp2OJi-BxC%20LAfEwHAE6GA3jAj6rYTQQGMEcMlmT6qWtnuTX%20jJa1MMdk6G6YfpxNhfYsAIfo%20uZbAu-kkgoknrZxBNQcsAG0fx-6hSJ4dl7WBHrbWAqJep1XjB18vGy7PE-7XBepAPFYN2O4F2e9Sm9epDrgfh7Pg%20p7vh%20rNPxbDzn3c%20bMiL0XIGRCoqpxA0RJpsKBMBGJhlSDXfO-N-a2SYEgDWQgUBXX4k%20PIL4261ALq6Dcvdn6VisNaBSudVYcS-jGRwF0hC91qANAETBhoEwyrQuo-IgjdGZOyUWY02hiT5EJIowpQiiUiN0CIWxyGzloVw2a%208x7Mi%20KsJgs9wCTS3C0DK4kC54D%20HVLSYhlQoC4CwJm%20i%20byVnjoggRIDE2gqAXLxfM4rGFMX3EKzsPEX0-Foyo4xMrEB4UNRwAjMq63YMIuRTAxH1GTtIogsjChChFCUMSPRVG1CruzSqxs2BYJwDgpARDsgkLrCSHAzJFRCyPIBXeIF0JS0oVYZk9AgIEHcP0RUr83Jlg8kM7pwgfD0BelIUGN0H7DDPuJGZwEMCzzMo0ewbsulbLpBuDCst2CBJAcwvu9c2F7PYAc4ZIF7SnI6pkw5IzG7PPUbUTZHyhDzJelon%2069xF3WZOjHwGBuhGJMVuDM6UWiSE0dUrKtTmBIGIIuZJmsLq1AReJHWmtjngQcFLCF2yJnBPfgfO5PiUXYPRfgwh8MC7gqBJCoBpiYnYCMvium8NyVuKqAgXFs4xAYC0had57haU%20RqXUq6FjShspLtsiJs5uW4G4Hys2FtBVUyjjHOO9ZpaQuZMsggt1cRKrEm4ylVLxWSvrNKjAsrfGlDqOSwJwSCLBNAeEi64wokxLMoqcG8U0GsAwQsbivENwuuITWUh1CEDtIqC69R-TOGOkeRgMZjDNKGiOkwDyZ0GhmNcFmIo5MaRpSKk1dgi9zH8tygzZqBdZ5rhbW2pmvz3BCrzoFEJ%20N5XosVayhAfa1VtiAA).

I'm struggling to make TS infer types based on the values in my array.

Comment: That playground example is quite intimidating indeed to me, since there's so much code in it.  Could you try to make a [mcve] which is *minimal* in the sense that there's only the code needed to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPjbzN) work for your typings?  If so I will write up how that works, but I *really* don't want to tie it back to that implementation in  the playground; you will very likely need to make liberal use of type assertions because there's little chance the compiler can verify that the implementation matches that typing.  If it doesn't work for your typings, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your playground. You're very close. Give me a moment to see if I can integrate your typing with my workaround. Will get back to you!

Comment: @jcalz Although your typings are correct. You're missing the actual implementation of the functions that should return the correct values.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I didn't really intend to implement the functions, since your issue seemed to primarily be with typings, as you had an implementation.  I guess your implementation wasn't general enough?  Anyway, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLRaew) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the typings, it looks like you want this:

```
function CreateColoursPalette<T, P extends Palette<keyof T>>(
  tints: T, palette: P): ToColoursPalette<T, P>;
```

where `Palette<K>` and `ToColoursPalette<T, P>` are defined like this:

```
type Palette<K extends PropertyKey> = {
  [k: string]: Array<K> | Palette<K>;
}

type ToColoursPalette<T, P> = {
  [K in keyof P]: (P[K] extends Array<any> ?
    { [L in P[K][number]]: [baseColour: BaseColour, tints: T[L]] } :
    ToColoursPalette<T, P[K]>
  ) };
```

A `Palette<K>` is an object whose property values are either an array of elements in `K`, or another `Palette<K>`.  This is a recursive definition which should allow you to pass in nested palettes.

`ToColoursPalette<T, P>` represents the desired transformation of the palette type `P`.  It is also recursive.  Let's walk through it: `{[K in keyof P]: ...}` means that it is a mapped type where the output value will have the same keys as `P`.  For each such key `K`, we check it to see if it's an array: `P[K] extends Array<any> ?` . If not, then we are recursing down, and we want the property value at key `K` to be `ToColoursPalette<T, P[K]>`. If so, then we want to take the elements of that array (which is `P[K][number]`, the type you get if you index into `P[K]` with a numeric key) and make a new object type with those elements as keys.  For each such key `L` from `P[K][number]`, we make the property value a two-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).   The first element is a `BaseColour`, whose type and details are not what you're asking about.  The second element is of type `T[L]`, which is what you get when you look up the property named `L` of the tints object type `T`.

---

The implementation of `CreateColoursPalette()`  in JavaScript should look something like:

```
function CreateColoursPalette(tints, palette) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(palette).map(([k, v]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      return [k, Object.fromEntries(v.map(p => [p, [baseColour, tints[p]]]))];
    } else {
      return [k, CreateColoursPalette(tints, v)];
    }
  }));
}
```

I'm using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to transform objects to arrays and vice versa.

The JS code is doing something quite similar to the typing; we are transforming `palette` into a new object with the same keys `k` and whose output values depend on whether or not the input values `v` are arrays.  If `v` is not an array, then we recurse down and call `CreateColoursPalette(tints, v)`.  Otherwise, we want to produce an object whose keys are the elements of `v`, and whose values are a two-tuple whose first element is some `baseColour` thing we're not concerned with, and whose second element is `tints[p]`.

---

This is essentially the whole thing, except that there is no great way to have the compiler look at the JavaScript code and verify that it conforms to the TypeScript typings.  If you try, you will tend to run into compiler errors.  To turn the JS implementation into something TS accepts, it will be easiest to just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) or the like to loosen/disable type checking of the implementation.  Essentially we are taking the responsibility onto ourselves for ensuring that the the implementation and the typings are compatible.

It could look like this:

```
function CreateColoursPalette<T, P extends Palette<keyof T>>(
  tints: T, palette: P): ToColoursPalette<T, P>;
function CreateColoursPalette(tints: any, palette: any): any {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(palette).map(([k, v]: [string, any]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      return [k, Object.fromEntries(v.map(p => [p, [baseColour, tints[p]]]))];
    } else {
      return [k, CreateColoursPalette(tints, v)];
    }
  }));
}
```

I'm using a single-call-signature [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to declare the typings, and an intentionally loose `any`-riddled implementation.  There's no compiler error.

---

We can now verify that it behaves as desired:

```
console.log(colours.primary.azure[1]["110"]) // "#FFE0AC"
console.log(colours.tertiary.neutral.sun[1]["10"]) // "#FEF0D6"
```

IntelliSense prompts with the right keys along the way, and the console log output demonstrates that the implementation is also doing what we expect.  Looks good!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigJwKYEMYYMIIA2CYaAPACoB8AFAB4BcyFAlExcgN7DLKYykUdANzIA9GOQwAFnADOyecjAAHKQmQBPEusUBbFYQx6MEGMiwQAJsgDmcAG4YpmlXAi2FMBKJnOrGDBYcIQKWJjIJOYIIMhyUAgqGMAAvsDAElKyCkqqutpgunAGRiZmFtZ2js4wru6e6r7S-oHBoRYRUZGx8YnJ7rhoIFhQzgBCWHL4RCRoXDyKACJIMADSEAgA7gDq0jgU2QCScgCC1ocAEn2HMHIAcggwAEoYRg6WMEwwaGAYwqnABIQOTmABGk2mxFITAmUwIULmAF55rw4MszOstrt9kdTucrkkbvdHi83h8vj9kml0rUksgAApYIwwXBkVbIDB0XDWBT0tB9NC1VYYTRUZDI7i8ADaAGsmCC0PUALpME5oNBYTRssUAHwZTMCrNWVH+1NpzgoCHhszkjOZrIoABoGWKJQspez3MgZSKYgyVcgaPSPUqOVzTFYFGqNVrLKLkAB+Ba8TjIKUAGUUKGDqyVUogYD0oIwaCVAal4LhM2hyFhkNmzvgZjk7AzZeQKWQDGTzCt1bQtoNLIwlGdOaVVAWLA7-3SmUOWUwmyySmKhmMpiC8CQ6lsgWaaG74Gg25QeEwOHrpEH9pHToZYe5kf1t7IPu0sWotAWTdu7GdKhDrgTD0mwvbWtedqGneY4mqAkCwIgZ4XrgEEDlBw40L+LYVJoAFARgTBxmBcYonwgSCMgADyoIAFYYLAAB0ID8noACiZiKhgcg0DR9FMZuXE8YBt4sIxehYCoNA0LKzoOOWCr1M6cZKtOiJipKvCKLENDRpqjHyHpmg0A4LDTppWnkQIaAoLJ1F0QxMDMaxHHfHA3EmeJkk0Go6lpiozoVhCaGNgMchSioZaqSwSr-JZnavFMZGWfwlF2ee2Cof2N7QVhYVyTFcVaWkvApGZprpOkQIglIYXimRciQEw6CZVeaA0BZyAAIwAAxMAA5AAxAAYmxw09YsABs-WOj2ADMfXIENw14GxPUnHgM09gArIty1jIsXUABxzVtllHXtI1HWMJwACy3WdWm9Zdw0AOwnGMXVjI9ZWzbwWAAF6kIRqAoW1HU9r1A0jWNE3TX9WkLdDK1rRtj28LtyMHcdp0I7wF3I9dd0PXj3U9S972fd9pNdVDS0jaN62bQjZWpLOgJIDVCQIgoyIZZeaE5Zh2HOppKiKhJaCaEwUr9Y1EAzUtgPA-1SoI1MQJWOE0tpnLkCqwjgzwNrTCdRAGBgN8TIy3rCvOv1yuYAbCwpLNZWzhAWAmHIgGjMw3FNrYhxmK8hDyKYSXcAs3M2ox4vFNrCwSHq8eS5oSdiHqGtIFrUsZ3qRtwInGfIAeFoAMpxNIJCEDY7ggCWkQQIQmjIHNyAqAgchyHAoJGJEKingoVi-LofgdDGFigggTjR9lccS9rjHy-ncSQKvjvJHPwLmEFVYIqFzahsiMfXgvCdS8vkBFdhUoAES9XfSqr71yB6gtb-ILtn8XZ-z3pLwU+A5l4MRzonXgyc14QAAageehdwHiEzsgc2lsNSEBgdVXelY2oACZD63BwcfWBPNGLwMvigq2hBGKbx-GFHB99H7PwgUg1+78eqf2-nqX+epnp-16ukakntva+wtAHeoVFLYqEtmRaqRAMCMWILYGgQC5DnzTtQoGmApRdTzA-Rh05Mh3wZqjPAd9t5yDkQohASiVGkJLMbchFtKFXwgNo3R+jEHICMaNcaU0zEpCAA)